# OANDA site form (VBA)

Tags: vba

I have a form with dropdown lists all of them have ID's

```
objIE.document.getElementById("form_quote_currency_hidden").Value = "USD"
```

then i submit form

```
 objIE.document.forms(0).submit
```

And it doesn't work. At the same time second dropdown list in same form works with this code

```
objIE.document.getElementById("form_base_currency_hidden").Value = "USD"
```

When i submit form it changes to currency i want to.

What is the reason why two similar objects in one form does not "behave" in the same way?

[image of oanda code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ5Jy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

if everything inside the Form element then, first we can assign a object for form and then try to execute a button,

Code:

```
Dim workForm As HTMLFormElement
Set workForm = objIE.Document.forms("ncc_detail_form")
workForm.getElementById("form_base_currency_hidden").Value = "USD"
```